# Photo source by... Tumblr?

Tags: ios, tumblr

How do the app [Cal loads images from Tumblr](http://www.blogcdn.com/www.engadget.com/media/2013/07/photo-1.jpg)?

I've seen that if you click on this photo source (it's a link), you go to [something like this](http://anydoanimals.tumblr.com/).
From what I understand, they are fetching all images from this user's posts. They seem to just reblog other posts they found with images.

1. Is it even legal?
2. How are they doing such thing?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the implementation details of a closed source web service 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are probably using the [Tumblr API](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2)

They also provide an Objective-C SDK ready for you to use in your projects [here](https://github.com/tumblr/TMTumblrSDK).

Regarding their policy, check [this](http://www.tumblr.com/policy/en/terms_of_service).

> When you upload your creations to Tumblr, you grant us a license to
>   make that content available in the ways you'd expect from using our
>   services (for example, via your blog, RSS, the Tumblr Dashboard,
>   etc.). We never want to do anything with your content that surprises
>   you.

Comment: But is it legal? I mean, what about the rights of the image owners?

Comment: I'd have to double check, but I assume anything a user uploads to Tumblr, belongs to Tumblr.

Regarding the API, it's a public API, so it's completely legal as long as you respect their License: https://github.com/tumblr/TMTumblrSDK/blob/master/LICENSE

Comment: Thanks for great answer. (i can only accept it in 5 minutes)

Comment: No problem, I just updated my answer with more info.